# MongoDB Aggregation: Multi-level filters within $addField

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Collection in the database:

```
[{
  "value": {
    "shipmentId": 1079,
    "customer_orders": [
      {
        "customer_order_id": 1124,
        "active": false
      },
      {
        "customer_order_id": 1277,
        "active": true,
        "items": [
          {
            "item_id": 281,
            "active": false,
            "qty": 1,
            "name": "apples",
            "attributes": null
          },
          {
            "item_id": 282,
            "active": true,
            "qty": 2,
            "name": "bananas"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "carrier_orders": [
      {
        "carrier_order_id": 744,
        "active": true
      }
    ]
  }
}]
```

Query I am trying:

```
db.getCollection('shipments').aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "value.shipmentId": {
        "$in": [
          1079
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "value.shipmentId": 1,
      "value.customer_orders": 1,
      "value.carrier_orders": 1,
    }
  },
  {
      "$addFields":{
          "value.customer_orders":{
              $filter:{
                    input: "$value.customer_orders",
                    as: "customer_order",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: ["$$customer_order.active", true]
                    }
              }
          },
          "value.customer_orders.items":{
              $filter:{
                    input: "$value.customer_orders.items",
                    as: "item",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: ["$$item.active", true]
                    }
              }
          },
          "value.carrier_orders": {
              $filter:{
                    input: "$value.carrier_orders",
                    as: "carrier_order",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: ["$$carrier_order.active", true]
                    }
              }
          }
      }
  }
]
);
```

Desired output:

```
[{
  "value": {
    "shipmentId": 1079,
    "customer_orders": [
      {
        "customer_order_id": 1277,
        "active": true,
        "items": [
          {
            "item_id": 282,
            "active": true,
            "qty": 2,
            "name": "bananas"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "carrier_orders": [
      {
        "carrier_order_id": 744,
        "active": true
      }
    ]
  }
}]
```

I am trying to apply filters at two different levels:

- “value.customer_orders”
- “value.customer_orders.items”

What I want is to filter out inactive customer orders, and within active customer orders, filter out inactive items. While doing this, if there are any attributes at the customer order level, we want to **retain** them too in the output.
How can I achieve this multi-level nesting of conditions and retain attributes using the aggregate pipeline?

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/hcNzTeAkiks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

1. `$map` - Iterate each document in the `value.customer_orders` array and return a new array.

   1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge the current iterate object with the document with `items` array.

   1.1.1. `$filter` - Filter the document with `active: true` in the `items` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "value.shipmentId": {
        "$in": [
          1079
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "value.shipmentId": 1,
      "value.customer_orders": 1,
      "value.carrier_orders": 1,
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "value.customer_orders": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$value.customer_orders",
          as: "customer_order",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$customer_order.active",
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "value.carrier_orders": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$value.carrier_orders",
          as: "carrier_order",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$carrier_order.active",
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "value.customer_orders": {
        $map: {
          input: "$value.customer_orders",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                items: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$$this.items",
                    as: "item",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$item.active",
                        true
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oN74WpjJY9Z)

---

**Solution 2**

Can combine the above filter within a single operator.

1. `$reduce` - Iterate the document in the `value.customer_orders` array and transform into a new array.

   1.1. `$concatArrays` - Combine arrays into a single array.

   1.1.1. `$cond` - If the current document's `active: true`, then combine with the array result from *1.1.1.1*. Else combine with an empty array. This aims to filter the document with `active: true`.

   1.1.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge current document with filtered `items` array with nested `item` with `active: true`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "value.shipmentId": {
        "$in": [
          1079
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "value.shipmentId": 1,
      "value.customer_orders": 1,
      "value.carrier_orders": 1,
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "value.customer_orders": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$value.customer_orders",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $cond: {
                  if: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.active",
                      true
                    ]
                  },
                  then: [
                    {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$this",
                        {
                          items: {
                            $filter: {
                              input: "$$this.items",
                              as: "item",
                              cond: {
                                $eq: [
                                  "$$item.active",
                                  true
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  else: []
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "value.carrier_orders": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$value.carrier_orders",
          as: "carrier_order",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$carrier_order.active",
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r0e0sojUK3r)